# Check if String contains value in list

Tags: ruby

I have a list of addresses and want to flag if they are American or Canadian. I have a list of US states and CA Providences. Is there a more ruby-like way to do this:

```
us = false
address = '1234 Fake Address Ave N, Funtown, TX, 59595'
address = address.split(' ')
address.each do |part|
  if USStates.include? part
    us = true
  end
end
```

Comment: Is USStates is a array?

Comment: USStates is an array.

Comment: Does every address contain a postal code? If so, it would be easier to test whether the postal code is Canadian (`\b/[a-z]\d[a-z] ?\d[a-z]\d\b/i`) or US (`/\b\d{5}(?:[- ]\d{4}\b/`).

Comment: @CoopDaddy: How do you recognize parts of the string which just looks like a state abbreviation, but is part of the street name? For instance 1234 NE Mulligan Ave, Nostate City, ZZ, 12345``? Although the state ZZ is not valid, your code would classify at as Nebraska, even the NE was supposed to mean "north-east".

Comment: @user1934428 I check to see if the address contains a state/state abbreviation and make sure the last word (presumably the zipcode) is numeric

Comment: @CoopDaddy : Well, in my example, the address **does** contain a word which looks like a valid state abbreviation (`NE`) and the last word *is* numeric, so your algorithm would accept it, even the state `ZZ` does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a one liner

```
address = '1234 Fake Address Ave N, Funtown, TX, 59595'
us = USStates.any? { |state| address.include?(state) }
```

Comment: What if the string were `'1234 CANUCK Drive, Victoria, BC, V8V 274'`? Even "Sock it to me." would be regarded as a US address if `USStates` contained both uppercase and lowercase abbreviations.

Answer (score 1):

```
us = false
address.each { |part| us = true if USStates.include? parts }
```